# PhpUnit inline DataProvider

Tags: php, phpunit

Is there a way to specify the test parameters directly in the annotation ? Something like this :

```
 /**
 * @dataProvider [[0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]]
 */
public function testAdd($a, $b, $expected)
{
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $a + $b);
}
```

Because it can be useful when the DataProvider is used only once with simple data set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe was added in [PHPUnit 4.8](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/Release-Announcement-for-PHPUnit-4.8.0).

Answer (score 15):

Thanks to Sebastian Bergmann, the solution is to use [`@testWith`](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/annotations.html#testwith) :

```
 /**
 * @testWith [0, 0, 0]
 *           [0, 1, 1]
 *           [1, 1, 2]
 *           [1, 0, 1]
 */
public function testAdd($a, $b, $c)
{
    $this->assertEquals($c, $a + $b);
}
```